# Ubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo Z50-70

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo, bios, 18.04

I want to know if there is no risk to install ubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo Z50-70, dis you test the new distro in that model of lenovo? Remember ubuntu 17.04 crashed the Bios of this model,  I wanna install this release (18.04) but I am afraid of crahs my laptop Lenovo Z50-70, becuase I nees dual boot with win 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this without any problem. The bios problem is fixed at the moment it seems.

Comment: Thanks Kevin RED, I will try to install it, I hope dual boot works correctly :)